# Cannot copy a Pinia state Array without referencing it

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, pinia

I am trying to create a duplicate copy of an array in a Pinia store. This copy is used for creating a reactive object in different components which is used to model inputs. Only if the user wants to save the changes, the copy array should be used to overwrite the original array.

However, the original array also gets modified instantly whenever the copy array is modified as if it was just a reference

```
  import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

  export const useItemStore = defineStore('item', {
      state: () => ({
        items: ['foo', 'bar'],
        itemView: []
    }),

    actions: {
    initialize(){
        this.itemView = [...this.items] //create a copy of original items array
   },
    edit(newItems){
        this.itemView = newItems
    },
    save(){
        this.items= [...this.itemView ] //save the changes
    },
})
```

How can I create a copy of a Pinia array which can be edited without updating the original?

In my actual use case, `items` is an array of deep nested Objects so I cannot simply do an array map function and copy each item's value

Comment: Afaik when using the spread operator you are not referencing the object itself, but since your object is deeply nested the objects *inside* your object are being referenced giving you this behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach to create a copy of a deeply nested object is to use

```js
const copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(items));
```

If importing a library is an option, `lodash` - `cloneDeep`can be imported separately via the [lodash.cloneDeep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.clonedeep) module. See the usage [here](https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep)

Comment: I went ahead with the cloneDeep option. Works amazing. Thanks a lot!